# Location of HtmlHelper instantiation for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am trying to debug a problem where HtmlHelper is null in extension methods.  Oddly the debugger claims it's fully populated, however I consistently get null exceptions.  I'm trying to figure out where HtmlHelper should being instantiated in an attempt to see where my problem may be.

Where should HtmlHelper be Instantiated?

**Update:**  In particular I am trying to implement the extension found here, http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/mvc-authorizedactionlink/, within a masterpage.  The error occurs on the MVC template's HomeController.Index().  There are some 'plugins'/virtualpathing that may be causing the problem (trying to avoid this can of worms), but, code the code is essentially the same as found here: http://www.codeplex.com/unifico.  However, I don't want to trouble anyone with the details of all of that.

Comment: Can you show us some code of your extension methods?

Comment: here's a link that could help you: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/01/13/extending-asp-net-mvc-htmlhelper-class.aspx

Comment: Can you show some simplified code that reproduces the problem? When & where are you calling the helper?

Comment: I am calling the helper in a sitemap.  It will take me some time to prepare, but, I will try and create a simple example (I should have done this before posting... ahh hindsight)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HtmlHelper is instantiated internally by ASP.NET MVC - it's not something you should generally need to worry about. Exactly where it gets instantiated depends on where you are using it.

The main place it gets instantiated is ViewPage's `InitHelpers()` method.

In ViewUserControls it gets created on-demand in the getter of the Html property.

In ViewMasterPages it just uses the ViewPage's Html property.

Comment: It's very difficult for ViewContext to be null - there are a number of safety checks along the way in the code to ensure that it doesn't happen. I recommend simplifying the code until you find out the exact cause. My guess is there's some code that's doing some pretty crazy stuff here.

Comment: Yea, I'm going to do just that... What really gets me is that the debugger and the (runtime?) disagree.  The debugger will show proper values in the extensions.  Thanks again

Comment: It looks like its some kind of interaction with virtual pathing.  I'm going a different route (heh).  Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

We've encountered this too (oddly, only on 1 of 3 machines), where we have a master page and the content page uses an HtmlHelper.DropDownList. What worked for us was adding `using System.Web.Mvc` to the master page's codebehind even though it was already in the content page's codebehind.

Comment: I never really did track it down... I recreated the same project and the problem didnt present itself...